# Watchdog for Android

Tags: android, watchdog, android-anr-dialog

To prevent ANR on Android you could implement a [Watchdog Timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer) which would require to have another Thread running and waiting for heartbeats. If you expect your App to have a refresh rate of 30FPS, guard for a refresh rate of lower than 15FPS. This covers also the case when you would have potentially an ANR in the future.

If you know the places where the UI might get stuck for a long time, you can build the watchdog to guard against this (skip current frame for example). **If it is to long why are you doing it on the UI?** If the action you are performing refers to redrawing the screen you can not do it somewhere else.

Here I made a simple example of a watchdog.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread watchdogThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        long lastT = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastCount = 0;
        long missed = 0;

         @Override
         public void run() {
            while(true){
                 if (System.currentTimeMillis()-lastT>1500){
                     if (count == lastCount){
                         missed++;
                     }
                     lastCount = count;
                     if (missed > 3){
                        Log.e("test", "Error");
                    }
                    lastT = System.currentTimeMillis();
                 }
                 try {
                     Thread.sleep(100);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         }
        });
        watchdogThread.start();

        startCycleUI();

    }

private void startCycleUI() {
    //Runs on UI Thread
    long lastT = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true){
        if (System.currentTimeMillis()-lastT>1000){
            if (count < 10) {
                count++;
            }
            lastT = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When you do not know where to look, is there a way you could build a watchdog timer that simply restarts the application? How can this watchdog timer live beyond the application context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the example from ["Java Source Code Warehouse" project](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/services/java/com/android/server/Watchdog.java.shtml)

You have options to:

- Monitor the memory in a particular process
- Kill the process if they don't return
- Check memory usage in the system, scheduling kills/reboots as needed.